# Python reading from file line by line and char by char

Tags: python-3.x

Basically I need to read from file char by char and I need to know at which line that character was. So it's a loop inside a loop.

```
keyboard = open(default_layout, 'r')
with open(default_layout) as l:
    for line in l:
                queue=0
                #i=i+1
                while queue != max_chars_per_key:

                        c = l.read(1)
                        <...>
                             if (queue==0):
                                key_name=c
                                key[c] = [key_name, queue+1]
                                <...>
                             queue+=1
                                <...bunch of code...>
```

The problem is, with this code after passing parameters it gives me:

> ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Any ideas on workaround?

Comment: This won't work how you think it will. There is a single file pointer, which gets advanced by **both** the `for` loop (line by line) and `c = l.read(1)` (byte by byte). When not make the inner loop e.g. `for c in line:`?

Comment: Well if I don't give it any parameters (it's a code which generates key presses based on the mobile keyboard layout and the given message), which is, If I store the message as a variable and don't pass it as a parameter by using argparse - it works fine and the results are as expected, however when I pass the message as a parameter - it points me to `c = l.read(1)` line giving that error.

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment addresses my question. The message you're being given is clear: if you mix `for line in l` and `c = l.read(1)` in the same code block you could end up missing some of the data from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get what you want would be:

```
with open(...) as fh:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(fh):
        for col_num, char in enumerate(line):
            ...
```

To put that into context with your code, it would be roughly:

```
keyboard = open(default_layout, 'r')
with open(default_layout) as l:
    for line in l:
        queue = 0
        for c in line[:max_chars_per_key]:
            ...

            if queue == 0:
                key_name=c
                key[c] = [key_name, queue+1]
                ...

            queue += 1
            ...
```